# What are the function-call/procedure-call pairs in GAP?

Tags: return-value, side-effects, gap-system

By [function-call](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap4.html#X78C70489791FDF43)/[procedure-call](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap4.html#X825803DE78251DA6) pairs, I mean pairs of functions that *do* the same thing, except one returns it's result whereas the other alters it's argument(s) to be the result. For example the pair `List`/`Apply`.

- `List(list, func)` Returns the list resulting from applying the function `func` to every value of `list`.
- `Apply(list, func)` Applies the function `func` to every value of a mutable list `list`, changing `list`.

I've become annoyed of writing my own functions to find that GAP already had a built in version I should be using, so it'd help to know these pairs. Like, does `Filtered` have a procedural counterpart I don't know about? Or do I need to write my own? If a function *does* have a counterpart will it necessarily be listed in the documentation for that function? The only other such pair that I can think of right now is `Concatenation`/`Append`. What are other such pairs of functions/procedures in GAP?

Comment: Although this may be of little help, as @ahulpke explained in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3704518/, "The general language convention is that verbs do something to an object, while nouns create a new object with the desired characteristics." So, a counterpart to `Filtered` would likely be called `Filter` - but there is no such function (and `Filter` has another meaning in GAP). We do try to mention counterparts in corresponding ManSections - if you find them missing, then please suggest improvements of GAP manuals.

Answer (score 1):

Although this may be of little help, as Alexander Hulpke explained in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3704518, "The general language convention is that verbs do something to an object, while nouns create a new object with the desired characteristics." GAP naming conventions are described in the GAP Reference Manual [here](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap5.html#X81F732457F7BC851).

So, a counterpart to `Filtered` would likely be called `Filter` - but there is no such function (and `Filter` has another meaning in GAP). We do try to mention counterparts in corresponding manual sections - if you find them missing, then please suggest improvements to the GAP documentation, preferably at the [GAP repository on GitHub](https://github.com/gap-system/gap).